# Why doesn't closing the last tab close the window anymore?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, tabs, gui, window

Recently, an update has changed Chrome's behaviour when I try to close the last tab: Now nothing happens, previously it would close the window. Since Dennis couldn't reproduce this issue on the same version, this seems to be some kind of glitch instead of intention on Google's part. What may be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? I can't reproduce this on v20.0.1132.57.

Comment: Also 20.0.1132.57 m. So it's probably not a change of behaviour but rather a glitch.

Comment: Do you have any of the many [last tab extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/last%20tab) installed? Maybe you had it disabled and recently enabled it.

Comment: Starting with the obvious: Can you close Chrome at all? Did you try a restart?

Comment: I can close Chrome, restarting didn't help. I don't have any tab-related extensions installed at all. Also, I have found out that closing the last tab sometimes work if I click many times.

Comment: Do you have the Chrome Toolbox installed, perhaps? One of its settings allows you to close the final tab without closing the browser.

Comment: @AlEverett That was it, would you like to post that as an answer?

Comment: @Erik: Sure. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the [Chrome Toolbox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn) installed, perhaps? One of its settings allows you to close the final tab without closing the browser.